# Display textfield with line breaks in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a form with textfields in Flask, and users enter texts line by line. When I look at the DB the enties are stored with line breaks but when I display it on my website, in Flask templates, it just joins the sentences and I couldn't display the text line by line anymore.

To illustrate, user enters text as

1

2

3

However, it looks like in my page as:

1 2 3

This is my code in the template:

```
{{ vroute.comments }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
<pre>{{ vroute.comments }}</pre>
```

HTML collapses whitespace unless you indicate otherwise.

Comment: Gold!!! Works thank you (would have added a + score, just my reputation is too low)

Comment: Since my answer helped you, please click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Thank you! Great question and great answer.

Answer (score 0):

please add:

```
style="white-space: pre-line"
```

to your html tag, for example

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line"> {{ vroute.commnets}}</span>
```