# How to ensure word wrapping within the screen width with html and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a web application on Flask, Mongodb, HTML and Bootstrap. My problem is that words in a table column go off the screen and I need to scroll browser window to read them.

Could you please give me an advice which bootstrap classes or additional HTML tags I should use to make word wrapping works well and the text in  tag fits in the screen size?

My HTML page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Field</th>
                <th scope="col">Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>{{page.page_id}}</td>
            </tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><pre><p class="text-break">{{page.body}}</p></pre></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And that is how it looks in browser (Firefox):
[image]

I tried to use different classes but nothing helped(
Thank you in advance!

Edit-1:
That is how my text exists in mongoDB:
[image]
So if I delete `<pre>` tag line breaks between paragraphs will lost and an appearance in the HTML page will be like on the screenshot:
[image]

Edit-2:
For those who will face the same problem this answer really helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618776/5908736

So I modified the HTML like this (added `<div>` tag):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Field</th>
                <th scope="col">Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>{{page.page_id}}</td>
            </tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>
                    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{page.body}}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And now it looks like this (line breaks from mongoDB are saved):
[image]

Thanks a lot for everyone!

Comment: You told the browser that your text was pre-formatted (`<pre>`).  If it is not pre-formatted, then don't use `<pre>`.

Comment: Thanks! But if I do so I will lost the line breaks between paragraphs (I added edit-1 to show the problem on the screenshots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `<pre>` tag.

If you need to set size
[sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/)
or
[overflow](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/overflow/)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I cannot delete <pre> tag because I receive the text from mongoDB with line breaks in it. I saw this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682457/display-textfield-with-line-breaks-in-flask) with the advice to use it and this really helped.

Comment: @Whatever22 may be it also can be useful in your case [word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag)

Comment: Thank you a lot! The answer is a little different, but I found it among the answers on the page you provided.
This advice (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618776/5908736) really helped!

Answer (score 2):

You Can add a class to your pre tag `class="text-wrap overflow-auto"`

In your Code

```
<td>Description</td>
<td><pre class="text-wrap overflow-auto"><p class="text-break">{{page.body}}</p></pre></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I have the result similar to that I showed in edit-1.

Comment: I think for that you can add text-align as justify